# Representation of power series of product of sine and cosine

Tags: calculus, power-series

Given $$ f(x)= \int \limits_0^x \sin(y^2) \cos(y^2) \mathrm{d}y $$

Anyone can help and guide me for this?I don't really have an idea of how to represent it as power series

Thank you!

My attempt: $$ 0.5\int_{0}^x \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{{(-1)}^n{({2{y}^{2})}}^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \mathrm{d}y$$ after substituting Maclaurin series of sin x

Comment: Why would you want to represent it (Who? Each of the functions or their integral?) as a power series?

Comment: @Timbuc represent f(x) as power series

Comment: Expand the integrand (after its simplification) as Taylor series and integrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\int_0^x\sin t^2\cos t^2\;dt=\frac12\int_0^x\sin 2t^2\;dt$$

and then you may want to check [Fresnel Integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral)

Comment: Can I check answer with you? [(-1)^n (2x^2)^(2n+2)]/2(2n+2)!

Comment: interval x in (-inf,inf)

Comment: @UnusualSkill You've been a member of this site for looooong time: if you want to be properly understood please do begin learning the easy directions to *properly* write mathematics in this site. I can't understand completely what you wrote, though I'm afraid it is wrong. Check the following : http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Comment: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{{(-1)}^{n}{(2x^2)}^{2n+2}}{2(2n+1)!} $$

Comment: It does not seem to be correct. Check your edit.

Comment: @Timbuc thx, so is it correct? $$x\in (-\infty,\infty)$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici i used standard maclaurin series for sin x

Comment: You had major typing issues. Anyway, what is this sum ? The integrand or the integral ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici this is the power series of f(x) ~~

Comment: @UnusualSkill It seems to be wrong. In the site I linked to my answer there you can find the power series you want, **but first** you must make a substitution in your integral so that you'll have $\;\int_0^x \sin u^2\;du\;$ and use the series there.

Comment: @Timbuc what site?

Comment: @UnusualSkill Read my answer! There is a link.

Comment: @Timbuc can you repost the link? I cant see it...the above 1 is the MathJax~

Comment: @UnusualSkill Click on "fresnel integrals" in my answer.

Comment: @Timbuc now what I found is:   $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac {{(-1)}^n{2^{2n}}{x}^{4n+3}}{(4n+3)(2n+1)!} $$   using the standard Maclaurin series of sin x as my  I only learned this, but I found what was wrong with my previous result. Is this correct already?

Comment: @UnusualSkill It looks right now. That's exactly the same I got.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** use $\sin 2u = 2 \sin u \cos u$; the power series of $\sin$ and term by term integration.

Comment: Can I check answer with you? [(-1)^n (2x^2)^(2n+2)]/2(2n+2)!

Comment: interval x in (-inf,inf)

Comment: it seems fine. edit your question with your attempt!

Comment: really?becuz other said it is not right...

Comment: my important attempt